# Typescript modeling: How to deal with an object coming from an API when the IDE doesn't know the structure

Tags: json, angular, typescript, api

I am pulling weather data from an `API` that sends a `JSON` object. Now I want to do something with this object and access one of its properties. But of course, the IDE doesn't know the Object structure and it tells me that the Property 'x' doesn't exist on type 'object'.
Nevertheless in practice the code works of course.
But is there any way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Create a model or type as any

Comment: Define an interface that aligns with the data structure being received, then cast the variable holding the structure to that interface.

Comment: If an answer solved the question you had you can click the checkmark on the left of the answer under the votes. This rewards the user that took the effort to help you, and makes it easier for members of the community to move on to other questions that still need solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your code, I think you could apply 3 different approaches:

**1) a simple solution is for you to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) `T` type:**

```
  public getJSON<T>(): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(url).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log(`JSON::get (tap)\n\tdata: %o`, data)),
      catchError(err => console.log(err))
    );
  }
```

You could define an interface like this:

```
export interface GenericServerResponse {
   [x: string]: any
}
```

And use this interface in your `component.ts` I guess.

```
public componentData: GenericServerResponse = null;
```

However this kind of approach takes away the fun of having typescript in the project.

**2) You could also use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), so that for example the service response could be of different types like so:**

```
public getJSON(): Observable<UserModel | AdminModel | SuperUserModel> {
  return this.http.get<UserModel | AdminModel | SuperUserModel>(url).pipe(
  ...
}
```

Or better since we will be reusing this, declare the type:

```
export type ConfigModel = UserModel | AdminModel | SuperUserModel;

public getJSON(): Observable<ConfigModel>
```

This is simple and more solid, but you will need to know the different models you could receive.

**3) This is how I think you should do it, since you must have the weather APIs full response, map the whole model 4 example:**

```
export interface WeatherModel {
   temp: number;
   wind: number;
   cloudCoverage: number;
   city: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
   };
   ... --> the rest of the model from the API, you don't necessarily have to put all the API's attributes, only the ones you use in your app.
}
```

Then you just need to use the [Partial utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt):

```
public getJSON(): Observable<Partial<WeatherModel>> {
  return this.http.get<Partial<WeatherModel>>(url).pipe(
  ...
}
```

Partial makes every property of the interface optional. This way the IDE will be happy and show you the object attributes.

And if you need to type data in the component just do the same with Partial:

```
public componentData$: Observable<Partial<WeatherModel>>;
...
this.componentData$ = this.httpService.getJSON().subscribe(
  (resp: Partial<WeatherModel>) => console.log(resp.city.name)
);
```